# How to make a loop with multiple foursquare queries and add every new query to a dataframe

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, iteration, foursquare

I have a Dataset that contains results from a query in Foursquare, but I need to keep filling/adding the same dataset with new data of different search queries.
Is there a way to create a loop for that task, I'm stuck

This is the example of what i've done so far:

```
search_query = [['food'],['sushi'],['pasta']]
radius = 1000
For i in search_query;
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id= 
    {}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&query={}&radius={}&limit= 
    {}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, 
    search_query, radius, LIMIT)
    results = requests.get(url).json()
    venues = results['response']['venues']
    dataframe = json_normalize(venues)

    df=dataframe[['name','location.address', 'location.lat', 'location.lng']].copy()
    search_query=search_query[+1:+1]
```

I expected `df` contains the Dataframe that have all data for every time the code es looped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you perform

```
df=dataframe[['name','location.address', 'location.lat', 'location.lng']].copy()
```

you create a new dataframe and assign variable `df` to that. Instead, use [dataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to add to an existing dataframe.
 Try

`df.append(dataframe[['name','location.address', 'location.lat', 'location.lng']])`